# what is the difference between ui-steps-number and p-steps-number in primeng?

Tags: angular, primeng

I found some code where the steps use ui-steps-number in one module but p-steps-number in another, and I don't know if ui-steps-number was the older version of PrimeNg and the new version now uses p-steps-number or are they different things entirely? documentation only talks about p-steps-number.

<p-steps [model]="items" [readonly]="true">

```
.p-steps-number {color: red;}
```

<p-steps [model]="items" [readonly]="true">

```
.ui-steps-number {color: green;}
```

https://primeng.org/steps/personal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeNG moved away from the `ui-*` prefix for CSS classes around version 10, opting to use the `p-*` prefix instead.

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/wiki/PrimeOne-Migration